# Continuity and differentiability of $g(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2}{\phi_{(x,y)}}$ at the origin.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> For $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2,~(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ set 
>   $\theta_{(x,y)}\in [0,2\pi)$ the angle between positive x axis and the line connecting $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$ and 
>   $$\phi_{(x,y)}= \left \{\begin {array}{ll}
> \theta_{(x,y)} &,  \theta_{(x,y)} \in [0,\pi)\\
> \theta_{(x,y)}-\pi &, \theta_{(x,y)}\in [\pi,2\pi)
> \end{array}
> \right..$$ 
>   Let $$g:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}: g(x,y)= \left \{\begin {array}{ll}
> \frac{\|(x,y)\|^2}{\phi_{(x,y)}} & , (x,y) \neq (0,0),~\phi_{(x,y)}\neq 0\\
> 0 &, otherwise
> \end{array}
> \right..$$ 
>   Determine if $g$ is continuous and differentiable at the origin.

*Attempt.* Since $\phi(x,0)=0$ and $\phi(0,y)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $x,\,y\neq 0$ we get: 
$$g_x(0,0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x,0)-g(0,0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0-0}{x-0}=0$$ and 
$$g_y(0,0)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{g(0,y)-g(0,0)}{y-0}=\frac{2}{\pi}\lim_{y\to 0}y=0.$$
I believe that $g$ is continuous at the origin, so I need to prove that $g(x,y)\leqslant h(x,y)$  for some h having limit equal to $0$ at the origin. But for $\phi_{(x,y)}$ being nonzero but small, how can we control $\frac{1}{\phi_{(x,y)}}$?

Regarding differentiability, we need to test if the limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{g(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

equals zero.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to see that $g(x,y)$ isn't continuous at the origin. Note that your definition of $g$, when viewed as depending on polar coordinates, basically decouples the radius (in the enumerator) from the angle (in the denominator). Since $g(0,0)=0$, it is enough to show that we can make the angle go to zero an order of magnitude faster than the radius squared (wich equals $x^2+y^2$):

Set

$$x_n=\frac1{n}\cos\left(\frac1{n^3}\right),\, y_n=\frac1{n}\sin\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)$$

for $n=1,2,\ldots$

That makes $\phi_{(x_n,y_n})=\theta_{(x_n,y_n})=\frac1{n^3}$ and $\lVert (x_n,y_n) \rVert^2 = x_n^2+y_n^2=\frac1{n^2}$.

So we have

$$g(x_n,y_n)=\frac{\frac1{n^2}}{\frac1{n^3}}=n$$

and thus $(x_n,y_n)$ is a sequence of points converging to $(0,0)$ for $n \to \infty$, but $g(x_n,y_n)$ not converging to $g(0,0)$.